# refer to activex listbox without using activesheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an ActiveX listbox named 'lbCCGs' on a worksheet.

This code compiles:

```
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.lbCCGs.ListCount
```

But this code does not:

```
Dim ws as worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("A&E")
Debug.Print ws.lbCCGs.ListCount
```

How do I declare and refer to an ActiveX listbox without using ActiveSheet? I've tried declaring it as an OLEObject and an Object but then properties like ListCount are not available.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use this instead? `Set ws = WorkSheets("A&E")`?

Comment: @braX No, no difference, I get a 'Method or data member not found' compile error

Comment: @Absinthe try the code in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Active-X `ListBox` try the code below:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lbcLB As OLEObject

Set ws = Sheets("A&E")

' Set the ActiveX List-Box object to a variable
Set lbcLB = ws.OLEObjects("lbCCGs")

Debug.Print lbcLB.Object.ListCount
```